# Can a dependent clause have no subject but have a predicate?

Tags: dependent-clause

I'm a bit confused by this example:

While fishing in the lagoon, he caught two fishes.

Is it a complex sentence? If yes, why is "while fishing in the lagoon" considered an independent clause when it seems to lack a subject?

Comment: While (he was) driving a car, he witnessed a car accident. If you use *he was* here, the sentence is not concise. You omit them as there is no one else who could be driving the car. If someone else is driving a car, you don't omit them.

Answer (score 1):

It is an [adverbial clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_clause) describing 'caught'. The subject is hidden:

While [he was] fishing in the lagoon, he caught two fishes.

Comment: That's a great link with lots of examples. Also, it isn't really an independent clause, like the OP states.

Answer (score 1):

"While fishing in the lagoon," is a present participle phrase that falls under the category of reduced adverbial phrase.  The subject in reduced adverbial phrases can be omitted if the subject in the independent clause is the same as in the dependent phrase.  In your case, it is.  He is the subject in both clause and phrase.  Your sentence is also a complex sentence.

"While" can be used to join two independent clauses.  "While I was working on my homework, my brother was helping mom." or "My car was leaking oil while I was driving down the freeway."

When the subject is removed from an independent clause, it become a dependent clause because now it relies on the independent clause for meaning.  "While fishing in the lagoon," means nothing unless you combine it with "he caught two fish." (I prefer fish instead of fishes.) which is an independent clause.

As a side note, writers often make mistakes by trying to make a reduced adverbial phrase out of a clause that has a subject different than the subject in the following clause.  For example, "While drinking a beer, the fish got stuck in the fisherman's net."  The reduced subject in the first phrase (the fisherman, for example) is not the same subject as the second independent clause, "The fish."  Grammatically, no rules have been broken but from a meaning standpoint, fish don't drink beer.

Comment: An alternative view of the last paragraph: pedants often complain about adverbial clauses where the omitted subject is not the subject of the main clause, sometimes calling them "dangling participles". They generally justify this preference on irrelevant grounds of logic. People who actually use the language continue to use the language and generally ignore the pedants; except when said pedants manage to cause them to doubt their competence in their own language, and thereby achieve their (the pedants') aim of elevating themselves by making others appear inferior.

Comment: @ColinFine I'm not sure how to understand this alternate view.  Am I the pedant?  Or is this your way of saying the last paragraph doesn't add anything and should be deleted?  Or...?  I don't know.  I'm sure you mean well, Colin.

Comment: I'm reacting to your describing a common English construction as a mistake. You are not alone, and it is certainly worth knowing that some people object to it; but the "rule" is a purely social one, and has nothing to do with either grammar or meaning.

Comment: @ColinFine if you have something to share with me, I am fine with friendly suggestions or advice from someone with more knowledge than I have.  Saying what you did was rather impolite and reflects on you unfavorably...I think I'm correct in assuming you would like to make a favorable impression on a stranger.

Comment: you're right, and I apologise. I get frustrated at the prescriptive attitudes to language use that often get presented on sites like this, and sometimes I go over the top. I had no right to take it out on you.

Comment: @ColinFine all good.  If you have suggestions for my answers let me know :)

Comment: No, apart from my sniping, I have nothing to add to your exposition. I found an example of a _dangling participle_ (which is what writers call this, where the subject is unexpressed but cannot be that of the matrix clause) in Thackeray today: _While thus approaching, as all hoped, to convalescence, Miss Briggs was the only victim admitted into the presence of the invalid;_ Miss Briggs was not the invalid, and so was not approaching to convalescence.